# How to control the click area in ListView item

Tags: listview

It is hard to say about this question. But I will try my best to describe it.

I want to design one chat tool. In the chat window I will show image and text content to user.
So there are some blank area. 
How to desired effect like this? When I click blank area, nothing is happened. When I click text content, I can get the item position.

Answer (score 0):

The ListView contains more than one sub-controll.

Have you se

Comment: Uups, there went something wrong while posting. So again:

Have you set all the required events?

For example when you have a self designed UserControl with a button and a textfield, then you can forward every event from the button and/or textfield to your own EventHandle.

To answer more clearly, I would need to get some more info:
-which ACTION on which CONTROL should provoke which EVENT/RESULT?

Comment: I get it.  Thank you for your help! ^_^